# How much energy is required to blind someone?

Tags: human-biology, vision

As I understand the ravages of sunlight upon the (human) eye; the cause of ocular damage and blindness is too much energy delivered to the cones and rods that ultimately make up our eyes; so the questions arise:

How much light can a (human) rod take?

How much light can a (human) cone take?

Comment: there are different kinds of damage.. high energy/high intensity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Light can affect retina in many ways [1]:

- photothermal mechanisms - exposure to intense flashes of less than 20 microseconds that cause a rise in temperature of at least 10 degrees Celsius [5];
- photomechanical mechanisms - exposure to flashes shorter than 5 nanoseconds [5];
- photochemical mechanisms - light is absorbed by a chromophore and leads to the formation of an electronically excited state of it, resulting in chemical transformations [5].

The retina is more susceptible to light induced degeneration at lower wavelengths [2, 8]. The damage degree also depends on intensity and exposure duration. 12 hours a day of more than 500 lux light, more than three consecutive days can affect rat retina [3]. 2 hours  exposure to white light of 3000 lux has lead to apoptosis in rats retina [4].

Sunlight irradiance is about 11 W/cm<sup>2</sup> (ranges between 1.5 and 122 W/cm<sup>2</sup>) and causes damage when exposure time is tens of minutes or even less [5].

Light induces apoptosis by different mechanisms:

> Intense light triggers cell death in cones and rods by two distinct mechanisms: rapid, necrosis-like cell death occurs in cones; prolonged, apoptotic death is displayed by rods. However, the areas of cone and rod loss coincide, suggesting some interrelationship [6].

Cones and rods have different vulnerability [7].

---

References:

1. Youssef PN, Sheibani N, Albert DM. [Retinal light toxicity.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21178995) Eye (Lond). 2011 Jan;25(1):1-14. doi: [10.1038/eye.2010.149](http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/eye.2010.149). PubMed PMID: 21178995.
2. Rozanowska, M. B. (2012), [Light-Induced Damage to the Retina: Current Understanding of the Mechanisms and Unresolved Questions: A Symposium-in-Print.](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1751-1097.2012.01240.x/full) Photochemistry and Photobiology, 88: 1303–1308. doi: 10.1111/j.1751-1097.2012.01240.x
3. Jin X, Wu L, Zheng H, Mishima S. [[Retinal light damage: I. The influences of light intensity and exposure duration at moderate and low intensities of cyclic light].](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12579740) Yan Ke Xue Bao. 1998 Dec;14(4):215-9. PubMed PMID: 12579740.
4. Remé CE, Weller M, Szczyesny P, Munz K, Hafezi F, et al. Light-induced apoptosis in the rat retina in-vivo. In: Anderson RE, LaVail MM, Hollyfield JG, editors. Degenerative Diseases of the Retina. Plenum Press; New York: 1995. Via http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2831109/
5. Malgorzata Rozanowska, Bartosz Rozanowski, Michael Boulton. LIGHT-INDUCED DAMAGE to the RETINA (2009). Available from http://www.photobiology.info/Rozanowska.html (accessed 20.07.2014).
6. Cortina MS, Gordon WC, Lukiw WJ, Bazan NG. [Light-induced photoreceptor damage triggers DNA repair: differential fate of rods and cones.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15180269) Adv. Exp. Med. Biol. 2004;533:229-40. PubMed PMID: 15180269.
7. Okano K, Maeda A, Chen Y, Chauhan V, Tang J, Palczewska G, Sakai T, Tsuneoka H, Palczewski K, Maeda T. [Retinal cone and rod photoreceptor cells exhibit differential susceptibility to light-induced damage.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/22220722) J. Neurochem. 2012 Apr;121(1):146-56. doi: [10.1111/j.1471-4159.2012.07647.x](http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/j.1471-4159.2012.07647.x). PubMed PMID: 22220722.
8. Kuse Y, Ogawa K, Tsuruma K, Shimazawa M, Hara H. [Damage of photoreceptor-derived cells in culture induced by light emitting diode-derived blue light.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24909301) Sci Rep. 2014 Jun 9;4:5223. doi: [10.1038/srep05223](http://dx.doi.org/10.1038/srep05223). PubMed PMID: 24909301.